# How to set widescreen monitor as main on a docked laptop?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors that's hooked up on my laptop dock. It's a Dell M4700 and I'm using a dock with it. One monitor uses DVI and the other uses display port. On screen settings, the laptop screen is already disabled but when booting up it still uses the laptop screen and I have to open up the laptop so I can to login at Mcafee Endpoint Encryption. How do I output the video right away to the monitors from bootup?

Answer (score 0):

I am not at my laptop now, but I have mine set up how you are trying.

I believe there is a setting in the BIOS though to choose a default display.